# python+smtp how to send email with attachment?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use smpt to send email with attachmant.However,my file is "doc" or "txt" type,and I want to send the attachment in "pdf" type.Is there unknown param can do this?

```
import smtplib
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
import os
server=smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect("smtp..com")
server.login("TTTTT@163.com","YYYYYY")
msg=MIMEMultipart('')
msg['From']="TTTTT@163.com"
msg['Subject']="opp"
with open("D:\log1.doc", 'rb') as f:
   content = base64.standard_b64encode(f.read()).decode()
part = MIMEApplication(content)
newfilename = 'resume.pdf'
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=newfilename)
msg.attach(part)
msg['To']="XXX@gmail.com"
server.send_message(msg)
```

use the code ,error happended!attachment file  cannot open! How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are mixing up three things: SMTP is the protocol you are sending the *completed* email with, the MIME type is the content type of the attachment as declared in the email and the actual content type the file has. If you want to send a doc file as pdf you have to convert it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just take a .txt file and email it as a .pdf.  You would need to convert it to a PDF first. You could try to rename the file, from .txt to .pdf, but that wouldn't accomplish much, because you would need to set the content disposition and content type.

https://www.davidfischer.name/2015/08/generating-pdfs-with-and-without-python/[How to create a PDF with python](https://www.davidfischer.name/2015/08/generating-pdfs-with-and-without-python/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import time
from email.header    import Header
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from getpass         import getpass
from smtplib         import SMTP_SSL
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart 

import smtplib 
msg = MIMEMultipart()
filename = "textfile.txt"
f = file(filename)
fromaddr = '*******@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'gamil addr'
#msg = 'There was a terrible error that occured and I wanted you to know!'

attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',   filename=filename)           
msg.attach(attachment)
# Credentials (if needed)
username = 'gamil addr'
password = 'passwrd'

# The actual mail send
#server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string() )
server.quit()
```